# jQuery is not revealing hidden table content

Tags: jquery, hide

I have a list of items where each of the items have related sub-items. I want to hide the sub-items unless the item in the list associated with them is clicked. But clicking on the main item doesn't expand the group. Would someone please point out my mistake? [JSfiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/1tbaf5c2/3/). The code is below

```
<style> .show-kids {display:none;} </style>

<tr>
 <td class="main-group">123</td>
</tr>  
<tr>
 <td>
  <table class="show-kids kids-123">
   <tr><td>123.111</td></tr>
   <tr><td>123.222</td></tr>
   <tr><td>123.333</td></tr>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>

<script>
 $('.main-group').click(function(e) {  
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(".kids-"+text).css("display", "block");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is because your HTML is malformed. You need to place the outermost `tr` within a `table`: https://jsfiddle.net/mg9op7bf/. Voting to close as a typographical issue,

Comment: Also note that the approach you're using is not ideal. A better approach would be to relate the elements to each other using DOM traversal methods, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/mg9op7bf/2/

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
<tr>
 <td class="main-group">123</td>
</tr>  
<tr>
 <td>
  <table class="show-kids kids-123">
   <tr><td>123.111</td></tr>
   <tr><td>123.222</td></tr>
   <tr><td>123.333</td></tr>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>
```

But you need:

```
<table><!-- open the table -->
<tr>
 <td class="main-group">123</td>
</tr>  
<tr>
 <td>
  <table class="show-kids kids-123">
   <tr><td>123.111</td></tr>
   <tr><td>123.222</td></tr>
   <tr><td>123.333</td></tr>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>
</table><!-- close the table -->
```

[Fiddle with this solution is available at https://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/qzb1wfkt/](https://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/qzb1wfkt/)

Also, consider this approach:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.headers_and_details').on('click', '.header', function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('table').each(function() {
      //if it's hidden, show it; if it's shown, hide it
      $(this).toggleClass('hidden-details');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden-details {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="headers_and_details">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="header">123</span>

      <table class="hidden-details">
        <tr>
          <td>123.111</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123.222</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123.333</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="header">456</span>

      <table class="hidden-details">
        <tr>
          <td>456.111</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>456.222</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>456.333</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This approach uses [jQuery's `siblings()` method](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to identify the details to be revealed, and uses [the `toggleClass()` method](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to handle the revealing and hiding of the details (click a header once to reveal; click that header again to hide).

You can see a working demo of this approach at https://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/L1nkeqvo/14/

Your scenario might also be a good use-case for [the `dl` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl).